Sale of Pyrotechnics/Pyrotechnic equipment in India. Legal aspect of this
Question is related to law in India, but anyone with any information about it, please comment or answer.
Link: https://trajectory-aerospace.squarespace.com/
I recently came across a website that is manufacturing and selling rocket components that are inherently unsafe and they aren't a registered company (pretty sure).
They're selling potent home-made pipe-bombs.
What are the potential consequences that can happen? They're selling these thing without any license.
I'm not a specialist but pretty sure there's a lot of licensing involved for mass manufacturing pyrotechnics and sale of pyrotechnics.

Not only the sale, but also buying of pyrotechnics is regulated in many countries, very similar to guns and ammunition.

@PMF and yet, criminals and terrorists manage to get hold of all of those things.

@DaleM yeah but do not deny the fact that without licensing we'd be having way more issues with all those.

Model rocketry is a popular hobby around the world. Do you think this company is using that as a cover for supplying bomb material? What evidence do you have, just that the company isn't registered?

Model rocketry is also inherently unsafe. They don't intend to supply bomb material, but they are doing so. They're supplying extremely flammable propellants, engines filled with the same, and igniters for these. Rocket engines are NOT to be home-made. Go to Space Exploration exchange and even type one word about home-made rocket engines and they will berate you for even thinking about that.
